# Comparing choice field from model in django template

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Skill(models.Model):

    title_choice = [
        ('LANGUAGE', 'Language'),
        ('FRAMEWORK', 'Framework')
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=title_choice,
                             default='LANGUAGE')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And the template(when compare with title) is

```
<h2 class="mb-5">Skills</h2>
            {% for item in Skill %}
                {% if item.title == "LANGUAGE" %}
                    <h3 class="mb-0">Programming Languages</h3>
                    <ul class="subheading mb-3">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
                    </ul>
                {% elif item.title == "FRAMEWORK" %}
                    <div class="subheading mb-3">Frameworks</div>
                    <ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
                    </ul>

                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

OUTPUT:
[output when I compare with title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72JF9.png)

When I try to compare the title from my model it doesn't show any data But when I compare the "name" with the database value it shows the correct output.
template(when I compare with name)

```
<h2 class="mb-5">Skills</h2>
            {% for item in Skill %}
                {% if item.name == "Python" %}
                    <h3 class="mb-0">Programming Languages</h3>
                    <ul class="subheading mb-3">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
                    </ul>
                {% elif item.name == "React" %}
                    <h3 class="mb-0">Frameworks</h3>
                    <ul class="subheading mb-3">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
                    </ul>

                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

OUTPUT:[when I compare with name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeIIi.png)

I want to compare the value with title and show the results

Comment: whar's the value of `{{item.title}}` ?

Comment: value is either "LANGUAGE" or "FRAMEWORK"

Comment: Is the value stored in the db also ? Did you check that ?

Comment: Yes they're store with a choice filed.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you want to be able to compare the Charfield against a CONSTANT in class / instance. To do that, you'll have to modify your code as below:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE = 'L'
    FRAMEWORK = 'F'

    title_choice = [
        (LANGUAGE, 'Language'),
        (FRAMEWORK, 'Framework')
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=title_choice,
                         default='LANGUAGE')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The value you define against the CONSTANT will be stored in the db i.e. 'L' for Language.

The second value in the tuple is what django will return when you call the `get_title_display()` function.

In your template you can now do:

```
{% if item.title == item.LANGUAGE %}
```

to compare against the choices.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices